# botframework error (Exception when trying to handle message.HTTPSConnectionPool)

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I integrated chatbot to microsoft teams using botframework. Sometimes I get this error while the application is running. What can I do about this issue? I am using nginx for http requests and ssl certificate is defined in it.

> Exception when trying to handle message.HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)')))

[enter image error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUO7h.jpg)

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: yes, it is continues